# How to disable Minecraft's resourcepack cache?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm building a plugin that dynamically generates a resourcepack, and then the user downloads it from a URL.

The problem is that during development I'm changing a lot of code, so I need to disable the cache in order to test it. I didn't find anything about Minecraft having cache, but when I hit "download resourcepack" the request never reaches the server, so it should have some kind of cache (maybe Java's cache?).

Comment: is it saved in the resourcepacks folder?

Comment: No, the server sends to the player an url and it downloads automatically